# Changing default highlight setting in Mojave

Tags: mojave, highlights

How can I change the default highlight setting in Mojave? I would like to choose my own less intense colours. Highlight annotation is greyed out, so it can't be accessed.

Comment: Greyed out ?? Would it be possible to share the screenshot ?

Comment: I should have been clearer. I'm trying to change the default highlight setting using Preview on a pdf file. Sorry, but I don't know how to attach\share the screenshot.